# PHP AJAX - Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093], what is this?

Tags: php, pdo

I looked around stackoverflow, there are lots of this kind of question. But I can't seem to find what is missing in the code.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\cases\traffic\traffic-insert.php:95 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\cases\traffic\traffic-insert.php(95): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\router.php(51): include_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\router.php(9): route('/traffic-insert', '/backend/cases/...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\routes.php(24): post('/traffic-insert', '/backend/cases/...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\cases\traffic\traffic-insert.php on line 95
```

This error came after solving this: 
[PHP AJAX - data update/edit inserts as new data instead of updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70179324/php-ajax-data-update-edit-inserts-as-new-data-instead-of-updating/70180190#70180190)

Here is the code:

```
<?php

include('./backend/config/connection.php');
include('./backend/config/function.php');

   if( isset($_POST["traffic_operation"]) ) {
       if( $_POST["traffic_operation"] == "Add" ) {
              $traffic_doc = '';
       
              if( $_FILES["traffic_doc"]["name"] != '') {
                     $traffic_doc = upload_image();
              }
              $statement = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO traffic_violations (
                     plateNumber,
                     carModel,
                     carColor,
                     violationType,
                     ownerGender,
                     violationDateTime,
                     violationLocation,
                     workingShift,
                     violationAction,
                     violationStatement,
                     cccEmployee
              ) VALUES (
                     :plate_number,
                     :car_model,
                     :car_color,
                     :violation_type,
                     :owner_gender,
                     :violation_date,
                     :violation_location,
                     :working_shift,
                     :violation_action,
                     :traffic_doc,
                     :ccc_employee
                     )
              ');
              $result = $statement->execute(
                     array(
                            ':plate_number' => $_POST["plate_number"],
                            ':car_model' => $_POST["car_model"],
                            ':car_color' => $_POST["car_color"],
                            ':violation_type' => $_POST["violation_type"],
                            ':owner_gender' => $_POST['owner_gender'],
                            ':violation_date' => $_POST['violation_date'],
                            ':violation_location' => $_POST['violation_location'],
                            ':working_shift' => $_POST['working_shift'],
                            ':violation_action' => $_POST['violation_action'],
                            ':traffic_doc' => $traffic_doc,
                            ':ccc_employee' => $_POST['ccc_employee']
                     )
              );
                     if( !empty($result) ) {
                            echo '<script>alert("Traffic Violation Added")</script>';
                     }
       }

       if( $_POST["traffic_operation"] == "Edit" ) {
              $traffic_doc = '';

              if( $_FILES["traffic_doc"]["name"] != '') {
                     $traffic_doc = upload_image();
              } else {
                     $traffic_doc = $_POST['hidden_user_image'];
              }

              $statement = $connection->prepare('UPDATE traffic_violations SET
                     plateNumber = :plate_number,
                     carModel = :car_model,
                     carColor = :car_color,
                     violationType = :violation_type,
                     ownerGender = :owner_gender,
                     violationDateTime = :violation_date,
                     violationLocation = :violation_location,
                     workingShift = :working_shift,
                     violationAction = :violation_action,
                     violationStatement = :traffic_doc,
                     cccEmployee = :ccc_employee,
                     WHERE id = :id'
                     );
                     $statement->execute(
                            array(
                                   'id' => $_POST["violation_id"],
                                   ':plate_number' => $_POST["plate_number"],
                                   ':car_model' => $_POST["car_model"],
                                   ':car_color' => $_POST["car_color"],
                                   ':violation_type' => $_POST["violation_type"],
                                   ':owner_gender' => $_POST['owner_gender'],
                                   ':violation_date' => $_POST['violation_date'],
                                   ':violation_location' => $_POST['violation_location'],
                                   ':working_shift' => $_POST['working_shift'],
                                   ':violation_action' => $_POST['violation_action'],
                                   ':traffic_doc' => $traffic_doc,
                                   ':ccc_employee' => $_POST['ccc_employee']
                            )
                     );
                     echo 'Traffic Violation Updated';
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Well the message basically says it all. Show the query and the code that executed it

Comment: Please don't refer us to different questions, but include the _relevant_ code directly in this one. Also, what is unclear about the error message - it just told you in pretty plain English what is wrong, did it not?

Comment: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` is the important part. You have more (or less) `?`s or `:param`s than the number of parameters you passed when you execute the query. This error message is explained in 100 places online already. If you're struggling to spot why this is happening in your own code, then please share it here.

Comment: lots of missing `:` in lines like `carModel = car_model,` which should be `carModel = :car_model,` So its just a **TYPO**, oddly the first and last columns are correct but all the ones inbetween are wrong

Comment: Help us help you - share your code

Comment: @CBroe If you're English, than it might look like plain English to you, but if English is not your native tongue it is rather difficult to understand. Things like "bound variables" and "tokens" don't immediately ring a bell. What ADyson wrote is a lot clearer. PHP error messages can be quite esoteric.

Comment: Apologies, code added.

Comment: RiggsFolly has explained your issue. The lack of `:`s makes it look to PDO like you specified no parameters, hence the error about the number of parameters not matching the number of variables. This could have really have been resolved by studying other people's (working) examples of PDO code more carefully... did you edit the post again since Riggs' comment, though?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the `:` but still the same error...

Comment: You have two queries in the question, which one is actually causing the error?

Comment: @ADyson The `INSERT` is working, but this error accrue when I try to `UPDATE`

Comment: Another typo: `'id' => $_POST["violation_id"]` is missing the `:`. Compare it to all the others. And learn to double-check your work more carefully...attention to detail is an important skill for a programmer.

Comment: @ADyson I thank you for your time. I fixed the typos but still.. nothing. I just wonder why the error is pointing at line 95 which is `':ccc_employee' => $_POST['ccc_employee']`

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it would. Are you sure about that? Bear in mind you've got one statement across multiple lines, so PHP will normally just point to the line which contains the start of the problematic statement.

Comment: `still.. nothing`...you mean the exact same error? Are you sure you're refreshing your page and making sure the updates to the code are being applied to the running environment?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, refreshing and testing. Still the same error. I'm still scanning the code to see where the issue is. However, the question I posted above, the code was working correctly except that the `UPDATE`. It inserts new data instaed of editing. John Doe posted an answer which I fixed my code with it. That's when I got this error

Comment: If it was inserting instead of editing then it was always running your INSERT and never your UPDATE. That's why you didn't encounter any problems with the UPDATE until that first issue was fixed. If you never run a piece of code then you'll never find any bugs in it! :-)

Comment: Are you sure it's _exactly_ the same error? I just noticed that `cccEmployee = :ccc_employee, WHERE id = :id` should be giving you a syntax error due to the comma (which needs removing) ...but that's a totally different error than the parameters not matching!

Comment: If we fix that, then the code seems to run without a problem - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c98c3e710e33d34ed096bd3e22ef3ecd88a590d9

Comment: @ADyson Yes, it was the comma. I can't believe a comma just broke everything! That made me giggle. Thank you Very much ADyson, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. But you would definitely have been receiving a different error message. It might have started the same way with `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException`, but the details would be different. Here's some honest, frank advice: You really need to get better at paying attention to details, otherwise you're going to continually have struggles with this kind of basic problem. In a computer program, every single character you type is significant, and when you're reading an error message, you need to read _all_ of it.

Comment: @ADyson That's what I'm honestly trying to do, Being self taught is not good. I would really need a programming mentor to guide me and I really took interest in you. Do you provide any mentorship services? (I hope I'm asking in the right place)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was with a comma:

```
cccEmployee = :ccc_employee,
WHERE id = :id'
```